# How to remove core functionality (SMS Cell Broadcast) from expo android app

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo

My expo app for Android has got rejected. Google says that

> The declared functionality {SMS Cell Broadcast}  is determined to be unnecessary or not aligned with the core functionality of your app.

At first I uploaded my `.apk` without adding any permissions due to which expo added SMS Cell Broadcast by default. Now I have updated my permissions according to the expo documentation, but I am still facing rejection. 
Following are my `app.json` permissions for android.

```
"android": {
  "package": "com.goziply.customer",
  "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
  "versionCode": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
    "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
    "MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"
  ]
}
```

I have tried contacting Google support but they didn't respond. How can I remove this core functionality from my Google play console?

Comment: What sdk version are you using? Should be in your `app.json`.

Comment: I am using "sdkVersion": "27.0.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to contact Google Support and to fix this issue they asked me to do the following steps:

- Create another `.apk` with higher `Version Code`.
- Create another release for the internal test track.
- Submit the new `.apk` with previous permissions.
- Release to Alpha.

The app went into another review and it was successfully published to the Alpha.